# BeautifulSoup - <em> giving me troubles with result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to put the titles in the `<strong>` tags into the `headerList` and the rest of the info in the `infoList`. It works for everything except for the `<em>` tag. I know I know, the HTML sucks but I didn't make it. Anyway, here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p><strong>MIKE ALSTOTT</strong></p>
<p><strong>Inducted: </strong>June 25, 2014 in West Lafayette, IN</p>
<p><strong>Date of Birth: </strong>December 21, 1973 in Joliet, IL</p>
<p><strong>High School Attended: </strong>Joliet Catholic Academy         <strong>Graduated: </strong>1992</p>
<p><strong>High School Honors: </strong><em>Parade </em>All-American; <em>Chicago Sun-Times </em>Illinois Player of the Year honors; rushed for 2,100 yards and 31 TDs as a senior; led team to 14-0 record and Class 4A State Championship as a junior with 1,820 yards and 26 TDs; also lettered in baseball.</p>
<p><strong>College Attended: </strong>Purdue University                       <strong>Graduated: </strong>1996</p>
<p><strong>College Honors:  </strong>4-year starting fullback; team MVP last 3 years; Purdue's all-time leading rusher with 3,635 yards, 5.6 yards per carry; holds PU record for career TDs with 42 and all-time, all-purpose yardage leader; holds several single season records; rushed for 100 yards or more 16 times; only PU player to accumulate more than 2,500 yards rushing and 1,000 yards receiving; as a senior, finished 11th in Heisman Trophy balloting, First Team All-Big Ten, and Gannett All-American.</p>
<p><strong>Professional Athletic Background:  </strong>Drafted 35th by NFL Tampa Bay Buccaneers 1996 and played there 12 seasons; forced to retire on January 24, 2008, due to neck injuries .</p>
<p><strong>Professional Athletic Honors:  </strong>Buccaneers won Super Bowl XXXVII in 2003; after being named 2nd team All-Pro in 1996, became first offensive player in Bucs' team history to be named 1st team Associated Press All-Pro 1997; selected All-Pro fullback 6 times; holds franchise record of 71 TDs; ran for over 5,000 yards in NFL career.</p>
<p><strong>Special Recognition:  </strong>Since retiring, has worked in private business in St. Petersburg area; established the Mike Alstott Family Foundation that supports the Children's Cancer Center, Ronald McDonald House, St. Petersburg All Children's Hospital, Sally House, and Big Brothers/Big Sisters in the St. Petersburg area; inducted into Purdue Athletics Hall of Fame 2006.</p>
<p><strong>Family:  </strong>Wife, Nicole; children, Griffin, Hannah, and Lexie.</p>
</td>
<td valign="top"><img src="/images/alstott_mike2%207-14.jpg" alt="" width="178" height="249" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my Python so far:

```
for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    headers = strong_tag.text.replace(':', '').replace('\xa0', ' ').strip()

    info = strong_tag.next_sibling

    headerList.append(headers)
    infoList.append(info)

print(headerList)
print(infoList)
```

Here is the result I am getting that I need help resolving. The problem is with the *Parade* because it doesn't capture the rest of the information after:

```
['MIKE ALSTOTT', 'Inducted', 'Date of Birth', 'High School Attended', 'Graduated', 'High School Honors', 'College Attended', 'Graduated', 'College Honors', 'Professional Athletic Background', 'Professional Athletic Honors', 'Special Recognition', 'Family']
[None, 'June 25, 2014 in West Lafayette, IN', 'December 21, 1973 in Joliet, IL', 'Joliet Catholic Academy\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 ', '1992', <em>Parade </em>, 'Purdue University\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0', '1996', "4-year starting fullback; team MVP last 3 years; Purdue's all-time leading rusher with 3,635 yards, 5.6 yards per carry; holds PU record for career TDs with 42 and all-time, all-purpose yardage leader; holds several single season records; rushed for 100 yards or more 16 times; only PU player to accumulate more than 2,500 yards rushing and 1,000 yards receiving; as a senior, finished 11th in Heisman Trophy balloting, First Team All-Big Ten, and Gannett All-American.", 'Drafted 35th by NFL Tampa Bay Buccaneers 1996 and played there 12 seasons; forced to retire on January 24, 2008,\xa0due to neck injuries .', "Buccaneers won Super Bowl XXXVII in 2003; after being named 2nd team All-Pro in 1996, became first offensive player in Bucs' team history to be named 1st\xa0team Associated Press All-Pro 1997; selected All-Pro fullback 6 times; holds franchise record of 71 TDs; ran for over 5,000 yards in NFL career.", "Since retiring, has worked\xa0in private business in St. Petersburg\xa0area; established the Mike Alstott Family Foundation that supports the Children's Cancer Center, Ronald McDonald House, St. Petersburg All Children's Hospital, Sally House, and Big Brothers/Big Sisters in the St. Petersburg area; inducted into Purdue Athletics Hall of Fame 2006.", 'Wife, Nicole; children, Griffin, Hannah, and Lexie.']
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.text` on the node? It gives all the text in the node irrespective of whether there are nested nodes

Comment: @bigbounty it gives me ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    headers = strong_tag.text.replace(':', '').replace('\xa0', ' ').strip()

    info = ' '.join([i if not isinstance(i,Tag) else i.text for i in strong_tag.next_siblings])

    headerList.append(headers)
    infoList.append(info)

print(headerList)
print(infoList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to replace the `<em>` tag.

```
html = html.replace('<em>', '').replace('</em>', '')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
...........
```